# how to exclude all target subfolders in perforce

Tags: perforce

I have a project like:

```
 /a
 /a/one/src/...
 /a/one/target/...
 /a/second/src/...
 /a/second/target/...
 /a/third/one/target/...
 ....
 /a/million/staff/other/target/xxx.class
```

I need to make p4 status to ignore all target subfolders:

```
 cd a
 p4 status
 <do not output anything is */target/*>
 cd one
 p4 status
 <do not output anything is */target/*>
```

Within p4 ignore documents looks like it's all about single folder, that is not my case

Answer (score 3):

Add `target/` to your `P4IGNORE` file.

```
C:\test>p4 status
dir\target\foo - reconcile to add //stream/main/dir/target/foo#1
dir1\target\bar - reconcile to add //stream/main/dir1/target/bar#1

C:\test>echo "target/" >> p4ignore.txt

C:\test>p4 status
No file(s) to reconcile.
```

---

If you need something a little stronger than `P4IGNORE` (e.g. you want to exclude `target/` folders that other people have already added to the depot), you can exclude these folders from your client view like this:

```
View:
    //depot/... //client/...
    -//depot/.../target/... //client/.../target/...
```